# Pine script if else if

Tags: if-statement, pine-script, trading

I'm new to Pine and can't get the following if else if to work on an choices input

```
// Backtest
entrySource = input(title="Enter On", defval = "Buy Big Green", options=["Buy Small Green", "Buy Big Green", "Buy Big Green Div"])
exitSource = input(title="Exit On", defval = "Sell Big Red", options=["Sell Small Red", "Sell Big Red", "Sell Big Red Div"])

entry = if entrySource == "Buy Small Green"
            wtCross and wtCrossUp
        else if entrySource == "Buy Big Green"
            entry = buySignal
        else if entrySource == "Sell Small Red"
            entry = buySignalDiv
        else
            na
    
exit = if exitSource == "Buy Small Green"
            wtCross and wtCrossDown
        else if entrySource == "Sell Big Red"
            buySignal
        else if entrySource == "Sell Small Red"
            buySignalDiv
        else
            na
```

I get the classic `line 489: Mismatched input 'wtCross' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'.` error but I can't work out why.

Comment: From PS v4 manual: https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Expressions_declarations_and_statements.html#if-statement and https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Operators.html#conditional-operator-and-the-iff-function

Answer (score 0):

you made small mistake with formatting **if else if** expression, try to remove indents like here:

```
//@version=4
study("Backtest", overlay=true)
entrySource = input(title="Enter On", defval = "Buy Big Green", options=["Buy Small Green", "Buy Big Green", "Buy Big Green Div"])
exitSource = input(title="Exit On", defval = "Sell Big Red", options=["Sell Small Red", "Sell Big Red", "Sell Big Red Div"])
wtCross = true, wtCrossUp = true, wtCrossDown = true, buySignal = true, buySignalDiv = true

entry = if entrySource == "Buy Small Green"
    wtCross and wtCrossUp
else if entrySource == "Buy Big Green"
    buySignal
else if entrySource == "Sell Small Red"
    buySignalDiv
else
    na
    
exit = if exitSource == "Buy Small Green"
    wtCross and wtCrossDown
else if entrySource == "Sell Big Red"
    buySignal
else if entrySource == "Sell Small Red"
    buySignalDiv
else
    na
plot(entry ? 1 : 0)
plot(exit ? 1 : 0)
```

Comment: ahh awesome thank you! still wrapping my head around this formatting